# Symfony 2.7: Automatically Populate Form Field from Within Form Builder

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an entity named HoursSpecial with a foreign key relationship to an entity called HoursArea. Each HoursSpecial belongs to an HoursArea. When I create a new HoursSpecial via my HoursSpecialType, I want the form field to automatically populate the HoursArea field.

I know what you're thinking, just do something like this in my controller's method:

```
$form->add('area', 'hidden', array('data'=>$area));
```

That would be fine except I need to make a DataTransformer to switch between the area's ID and the actual area entity. So I have to declare my HoursArea field within my HoursSpecialType with the transformer:

```
    $builder
        ...
        ->add('area', 'hidden')
    ;

    $builder->get('area')->addModelTransformer(new HoursAreaToIntTransformer($this->manager));
```

Now, I can't simply feed my HoursArea entity into the form. Is there an effective way to make this happen?

I've thumbed through Symfony's documentation on [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-underlying-data), but I can't make heads or tails of how I would pass in that HoursArea entity dynamically from outside of the form builder. Maybe I'm just missing something?

**UPDATE**

Following the recommendation of the answer (Recommendation #1) below from @Ryan, I have created the custom type HiddenHoursAreaType:

```
// AppBundle\Form\Type\HideenHoursAreaType.php
class HiddenHoursAreaType extends AbstractType
{
//need to instantiate HoursAreaToIntTransformer
private $manager;

public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
{
    $this->manager = $manager;
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $transformer = new HoursAreaToIntTransformer($this->manager);
    $builder->addModelTransformer($transformer);
}



public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => null,
        'compound' => true  //this should be FALSE as there are no children
    ));
}

/**
 * 
 * the return value of the getParent function indicates that you're extending the choice field type. 
 * This means that, by default, you inherit all of the logic and rendering of that field type.
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return 'hidden';
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'app_hoursArea';
}
```

I have added my transformer into the custom type class. Here is the transformer class:

```
// AppBundle\Form\DataTransformer;
class HoursAreaToIntTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms an object (HoursArea) to a string (number).
     *
     * @param  Issue|null $issue
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($area)
    {
        if (null === $area) {
            return '';
        }

        return $area->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a string (number) to an object (HoursArea).
     *
     * @param  string $areaId
     * @return HoursArea|null
     * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (HoursArea) is not found.
     */
    public function reverseTransform($areaId)
    {
        // no area number? It's optional, so that's ok
        if (!$areaId) {
            return;
        }

        $area = $this->manager
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:HoursArea')
            // query for the issue with this id
            ->find($areaId)
        ;

        if (null === $area) {
            // causes a validation error
            // this message is not shown to the user
            // see the invalid_message option
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                'An area with number "%s" does not exist!',
                $areaId
            ));
        }

        return $area;
    }
}
```

Within my controller I create the form with the custom type field:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new HoursSpecialType($this->getDoctrine()->getManager()), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('hoursspecial_postcreate'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));
    $form->add('eventDate', 'hidden', array('data'=>$dateString));
    $form->add('area', new \AppBundle\Form\Type\HiddenHoursAreaType($this->getDoctrine()->getManager()), array(
        'data'=>$area,
        'invalid_message'=>'Area field not converted proerly'
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));
```

Thanks to the transformer and the custom type, the form now correctly converts the HoursArea entity to an integer for population in the hidden field.

**The problem now is that upon form submission, the integer is not converted back into an HoursArea object. I know this because I get the 'invalid_message' upon submission.**

**Final Update**

The reason the HoursArea id wasn't being inserted properly had something to do with the

```
'compound' => true
```

setting I had in my custom type. I assume it was looking for child fields and wasn't finding any...which it shouldn't have because there were none!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You could create a custom type for it and add the `addModelTransformer()` call in the `buildForm()` of your custom type, but still pass the data in explicitly. So your `$form->add('area', 'hidden', array('data'=>$area))` would become `$form->add('area', new HiddenHoursAreaType(), array('data'=>$area))` where `HiddenHoursAreaType::getParent()` would be the `hidden` type.
2. You could set the data in a `POST_SET_DATA` listener.
3. You could get the `$options['data']` value in `buildForm()` and explicitly pass in the `HoursArea` ID.

   ```
   /** @var HoursSpecial $hoursSpecial Prepopulated in controller */
   $hoursSpecial = $options['data']
   $builder->add('area', 'hidden', ['data' => $hoursSpecial->getHoursArea()->getId()])
   ```

Comment: I've gotten most of the way there hooking up the transformer to a custom type. However, I'm having trouble re-converting the HoursArea id back into an entity for persistence into the database. Please see my updated example.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `compound=>true`?

Comment: Is your `reverseTranform()` getting called at all?

Comment: Looks like the issue was with the compound=>true, which I was playing with before I got the configuration right for the custom type. Thanks for picking up on that.